# Buttons do not work on ipad1, while working normally in simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, button, simulator

I have a test app for HTML Put functionality. There are buttons, for example a post button wherewith data is posted, but they all don't perform their actions. You can see them pressed and so on, but the selector doesn't work. In the simulator it works fine, but on my ipad1 nothing happens when you push any button except for the button being highlighted as it is pressed. Anyone any idea what's going on here? I would like to have the buttons function normally, that is: they should perform their given actions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a gesture recognizer over it. It worked in simulator but not on device. The gesture recognizer took the event away so nothing happens. Also needed this to work:

`gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;`

Also I needed to set the delegate to self of the gestureRecognizer.